# when I received mismatching data,I need to send response as status code as 400 and status code as 500 for server issues from sales force to google

Tags: salesforce, response, rest, sfdc

I try to get bad request error using below .json,But I am not getting .I want send this response.

For example:

1. validation errors:
   {
   "StatusCode":"400",
   "id":"",
   "error":"xxxx"
   }
   2.Internal Server error:
   {
   "StatusCode":"500",
   "id":"",
   "error":"xxxx"
   }

   Apex REST API class :

   @RestResource(urlMapping='/IoT_Case__c/*')
   global with sharing  class IOT_CaseManager {
   global class ResponseWrapper{

   ```
           public String StatusCode;
           public String StatusMessage;
           public String ErrorMessage;
           public String ID;
           //public List<IoT_Case__c> Details;


       }  
      @HttpPost
       global static ResponseWrapper createIOT_Case(String IOT_Case_Type,
                                      String Name,String Email,String Phone,String Facility_Name,
                                      String Address,String case_Reason,string Device_ID,
                                      String Date_time, String Pool_Name){

          RestRequest request = RestContext.request; 
          ResponseWrapper resp = new ResponseWrapper(); 
          system.debug('%%%%%% the response is######'+resp);  


          List<IoT_Case__c>  caseList = new List< IoT_Case__c> ();
     try{ 
                IoT_Case__c   Iot_case = new IoT_Case__c (); 

                Iot_case.IOT_Case_Type__c=IOT_Case_Type;   
                Iot_case.Name__c= Name;
                Iot_case.Email__c= Email;     
                Iot_case.Phone__c= Phone;
                Iot_case.Address__c= Address;
                Iot_case.Pool_Name__c= Pool_Name;     
                Iot_case.Device_ID__c= Device_ID;
                Iot_case.case_Reason__c=case_Reason;
                Iot_case.Facility_Name__c=Facility_Name;
                Iot_case.Date_time__c=Date.valueOf(Date_time); 
             caseList.add(Iot_case);         

        if (caseList.size() > 0){                  
        List<IoT_Case__c> Iotcase_List = [SELECT ID,Name__c,case_Reason__c,Device_ID__c,IOT_Case_status__c from IoT_Case__c]; 
       // system.debug('@@@@the value is &&&&&'+ Iotcase_List);
        For (Iot_case__c ic:Iotcase_List){            

        if ((ic.IOT_Case_status__c == 'Open'|| ic.IOT_Case_status__c == 'In -Progress') && (ic.case_Reason__c == caseList[0].case_Reason__c && ic.Device_ID__c == caseList[0].Device_ID__c)){                
            resp.errorMessage='Duplicate case'; 
            system.debug('@@@@the value is &&&&&'+resp.errorMessage );            
          }
    } 
      if(resp.errorMessage!='Duplicate case'){

             insert caseList; 
              resp.statusCode ='201';
              resp.statusMessage ='Success' ;

        }
          else{
              resp.statusCode ='409';
              resp.statusMessage ='Duplicate' ;
            }
        }          
    } 
       catch (Exception e) {  

         system.debug('&&&&&&& The errro message is *****'+ e);

         if(e.getMessage().contains('Validation'))
           {
           resp.statusCode = '400';
           resp.statusMessage = 'Exception : ' + e.getMessage();   
           } 
           if(e.getMessage().contains('Internal server error '))
           {
           resp.statusCode = '500';
           resp.statusMessage = 'Exception : ' + e.getMessage();   
           }  
       } 
        string Outputget= JSON.serialize((caseList));

              //resp.Details = caseList;
              resp.ID = caseList[0].Id; 
              system.debug('@@@@@@the response id is&&&&&'+resp.ID );
              //resp.ErrorMessage= 'Exception ' ;

       return resp; 
      } 
   }

   json :

   {
       "IOT_Case_Type": "Equipment_Replacement",
       "Name": "test123",
       "Email": "test1@gmail.com",
       "Phone": "9086978010",
       "Address": "Chennai",
       "Pool_Name": "Pool-1",
       "Facility_Name": "Facility-1",
       "Device_ID" : "D1110" ,
       "case_Reason"  : "FAC Sensor Expired,ORP Sensor Expired,pH Sensor Expired",
       "Date_time": "2021-02-01T03:42:22Z" 
   }

   endpoint Post url :/services/apexrest/IoT_Case__c/*
   ```

Answer (score 0):

```
 if(e.getMessage().contains('FIELD_CUSTOM_VALIDATION_EXCEPTION'))
        {
        resp.statusCode = '400';
        resp.statusMessage = 'Exception : ' + e.getMessage();
        resp.ErrorMessage= 'Bad Request Exception' ;   
        } 
       else{
        resp.statusCode = '500';
        resp.statusMessage = 'Exception :' + e.getMessage(); 
        resp.ErrorMessage= 'Internal server Exception ' ;  
       }
```

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Answer (score 0):

```
I need test class with 80% code coverage for above class . 
I tried this but i am getting 58% code coverage only .
@isTest
Public class IOT_CaseManagerTest{
    static testMethod void testDoPost(){
      
      IoT_Case__c  Iot_case = new IoT_Case__c(); 
            Iot_case.IOT_Case_Type__c='Equipment_Replacement';   
             Iot_case.Name__c='';
             Iot_case.Email__c='test1@gmail.com';     
             Iot_case.Phone__c='9573678567';
             Iot_case.Address__c='Chennai';
             Iot_case.Pool_Name__c='Pool-1';     
             Iot_case.Device_ID__c='CAS968878';
             Iot_case.case_Reason__c='FAC Sensor Expired,ORP Sensor Expired,pH Sensor Expired';
             Iot_case.Facility_Name__c='Facility-1';
             Iot_case.Date_time__c=system.Today(); 
          insert Iot_case;
           Test.startTest();
             IOT_CaseManager.createIOT_Case('Equipment_Replacement','sreenitest','test1@gmail.com','9573678567','Chennai','Pool-1','CAS968878','FAC Sensor Expired','Facility-1','8/25/2021');
           Test.stopTest();
    }      
    static testMethod void testPostMethod()
     {
        RestRequest request = new RestRequest();
        request.requestUri ='/services/apexrest/IoT_Case__c/*';
        request.httpMethod = 'POST';
        RestContext.request = request;
        IOT_CaseManager.createIOT_Case('Equipment_Replacement','sreenitest','test1@gmail.com','9997877','Chennai-2','Pool-1','CAS968898','FAC Sensor Expired','Facility-1','8/25/2021');
        //System.assert(strId !=null );
     }          
 }
```